# Is there a function $*:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ which has a "retraction" which ignores order in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, machine-learning, integers

When working with machine learning models I came across a regression model that has 2 integer outputs for which the order doesn't matter. It would be convenient to map this two outputs into one real one such that the integers can be recoverd from this real number. Thus the question:

Is there any function $*:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ with associated map $A:Im(*)\to\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that for any $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$A(p*q)=(p,q) \vee A(p*q)=(q,p)$$

Comment: what do you mean by $(p,q)$?

Comment: @DonThousand an ordered pair of course.

Comment: What is the V operation that seems to be between pairs? Can you provide some words, some context, perhaps an example of sample input/output? Please [edit] the question, don't use comments to clarify.

Comment: Right, and $A(p*q)=(p,q)\vee A(p*q)$? That just doesn't seem right.

Comment: Not clear why you'd want $A$ to work on all $\mathbb R,$ rather than just the range of $*.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right. I'm going to fix it

Comment: @EthanBolker This is the standard mathematical symbol for logical or.

Comment: You can define $a*b=\min(a,b)+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}+|a-b|}.$ Then $$A(z)=\left(\lfloor z\rfloor,\lfloor z\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{1}{z-\lfloor z\rfloor}\right\rfloor-2\right)$$ where you'll need some default when $z$ is an integer (and thus this $A(z)$ is not defined - but $a*b$ is never an integer.)

Comment: @FallenApart while I understand your question (And there seem to be two good answers now), you should be aware that most of these will not be very useful in machine learning. Most of these functions are not continuous, and $A$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, and so most applications will not handle these well. While the question is a reasonable one on its own, I strongly recommend against using this approach almost any ML setting. If you want more ideas on how to do it, feel free to chat.

Answer (score 2):

Without any constraints on $\ast$ and $A$, this simply follows from cardinality arguments. Since $|\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}|\le |\mathbb{R}|$ (via the well known fact that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable), there must exist an injective function $\ast : \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$. When restricted to it's image this function $\ast$ will have an inverse $A$.
Explicit examples are numerous and given by some of the comments and other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If "$X \vee Y = Z$"  means just that at least one of $X, Y$ is $Z$ then all you are really asking is that
$$
A(p*q) = (q,p)
$$
since then
$$
(p,q) \vee (q,p) = (q,p)
$$
will be true.

There are lots of pairs of functions  $(*, A)$ that will do. You just have to encode a pair as a single number that uniquely determines both $p$ and $q$. Then let  $A$ be the function for which
$$
A(p*q) = (q,p) ,
$$

If there is a bound $b$ on nonnegative inputs just convert $(p,q)$ to a  digit base $b$ integer:
$$
p*q = pb + q.
$$

For arbitrary integer inputs, setting
$$
p*q = 2^p3^q
$$
produces a rational number from which you can recover $p$ and $q$ by factoring.

If you want integer rather than a rational output use $2^p$ or $3^{-p}$ depending on the sign of $p$, and a power of $5$ or $7$ to encode $q$.

There are many other strategies. Picking one that works best for the application depends on context you haven't provided.

Comment: Where do you see $X\lor Y=Z$? It says $A(z)=X\lor A(z)=Y.$

Comment: ... which has the unique meaningful interpretation $(A(z)=X)\lor(A(z)=Y)$. There's not need to require parentheses around equalities that are next to a $\lor$ or other logical connective, because $=$ _must_ bind tighter than the $\lor$.